AWS CloudFormation with Read-only parameter type
I'm new to CloudFormation and I need some help in this.
I have created a CloudFormation Stack where I want to show a read-only field or a label that needs to show the current region, a list of AZs in that region, and the count of AZs under the parameters section where we provide the values for the parameters.
Or else may I able to show an alert?
Thanks in advance.
